# How to get upcoming row id - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

For example, the lastest row id is 100. I insert a new row and then delete it and then insert again. The row id is gonna be 102. How can I get that number 102 before inserting a new row.

Note: `Model.maximum(:id).next` only gives me 101.

Comment: Check your `sqlite_sequence` table. https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `SQLITE_SEQUENCE`, where all auto-increments are stored.

First, create your query:

```rb
sql = "SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE"
```

Then execute your query to get the next id to be set:

```rb
next_id = Hash[ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)]["table"] + 1
```

Where `table` is the name of the table you want the auto-increment from (usually plural of `Model`).

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, how can I put the query in a haml file?

Comment: Do you mean to put the _result_ of the query in the html file? Use `@next_id` instead of `next_id` in your controller, and in your haml file use that variable, something like: `%p= @next_id` (this exmaple will show the id in a `<p>` tag).

Comment: I did it and it returns the id 0 for some reason

Comment: Do I need these 2 rows `sql = "SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE"
  @next_id = Hash[ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)]["landslides"] + 1` in a method in the controller?

Comment: Yes, that way you set the `@next_id` variable and make it available to your view (haml file).

Comment: Here's my method in controller `def getLandslideID
    sql = "SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE"
    @next_id = Hash[ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)]["landslides"] + 1
    return @next_id
  end`. How can I retrieve it in the view

Comment: Do you get 0 if you use that code in _rails conosle_? Try doing doing, this, open a rails console (`rails c`), set the `sql` variable and just run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)` to see the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143092/discussion-between-gerry-and-tri-nguyen).